# Can we implement micrometer metrics in a vert.x groovy application?

Tags: gradle, groovy, metrics, vert.x, micrometer

I am working a groovy vert.x application and I need to collect metrics on the throughput of messages coming through a WSClient. I have tried using Vert.x Metrics Service Provider Interface (SPI) reporting metrics to the Dropwizard metrics library as well as the one reporti[enter image description here][1]ng to micrometer but I keep getting error in import statements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

Here is a code snippet that may help you
https://gist.github.com/asad-awadia/93ba7c1eba6d6b8a8a84e9f20721d983